# Error in installing VirtualBox for coolc compiler in ubuntu

Tags: compiler-errors, virtualbox

I am taking a course on compiler at coursera. Here is link for it,
https://www.coursera.org/course/compilers. I have successfully download virtualbox from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads.I tried to install it in my ubuntu15.04 as given in its user manual.I used command

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb
```

I found an error as given below

```
(Reading database ... 241558 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-5.0_5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty_i386.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.0 (5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty) over (5.0.10-104061~Ubuntu~trusty) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-5.0:
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.20).
 virtualbox-5.0 depends on libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0).

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-5.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.14-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+15.04.20150202-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-5.0
```

I didn't understand what's going wrong? can someone help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link will help you fix the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/666026/virtualbox-5-0-installation-has-broken-virtualbox-packages-on-kubuntu-15-04

I added the solution provided in the link down:

You have to completely remove older VirtualBox versions before installing VirtualBox-5.0 !

Uninstall VirtualBox -> `sudo apt-get purge "^virtualbox-.*"`

Check carefully what will be removed before you confirm.

Update the software repositories -> `sudo apt-get update`

Clean up -> `sudo apt-get autoremove | sudo apt-get autoclean | sudo apt-get clean`

Create a file oracle-vbox.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder and add the following lines:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib  
# deb-src http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib
```

Note : This answer was written in times of Ubuntu 15.04.

If you don't use 15.04, replace vivid with the codename of your Ubuntu version, e.g. trusty for 14.04 LTS or wily for 15.10!

Download and register the ORACLE public key:

```
wget -q -O - https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Update software repositories again -> sudo apt-get update

Install VirtualBox -> `sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.0`

Comment: WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.19.0-15-generic) or it failed to
         load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
VirtualBox: Error -10 in SUPR3HardenedMain!
VirtualBox: Effective UID is not root (euid=1000 egid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000)

VirtualBox: Tip! It may help to reinstall VirtualBox.

Comment: `# modprobe vboxdrv`
to auto load the module at boot add vboxdrv to modules array in /etc/rc.conf

Comment: if this didn't work try these commands:
First install the kernel headers and build tools.

`$ sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant `
`$ sudo m-a prepare`
And now compile virtualbox kernel driver with the commanded as reported by the error message earlier.

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`